# java programme trouble get next note in piano programme

Tags: java, project

i need some help with a project i am working on, i need to make a piano programme that store the keys pressed on a gui of a piano in an arraylist then when a play button is pressed i need it to play back the tune made. the code i have is here; any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
import student.NoteStore;

/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */
public class Notestore implements NoteStore {

    ArrayList<Integer> tune = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addNote(int note) {
        tune.add(note);
    }

    public void getNextNote(int note) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tune.size(); i++) {
            tune.get(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNextNote() {

        if ( == true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(int sortOrder) {
        NoteStore ns = new Notestore();
        ns.addNote(60);
        ns.addNote(62);
        ns.addNote(58);

        //start (with the notes in tune order)
        ns.start(2);
        int note1 = ns.getNextNote();
        int note2 = ns.getNextNote();

        //start again (with the notes in tune order)
        ns.start(2);
        int note3 = ns.getNextNote();

        System.out.println("Notes were " + note1 + "," + note2 + "," + note3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: What is start supposed to do? Print out the notes? Why aren't you just using a for each?